# How to use LayeredHighlighter - One highlight on top of another

Tags: java, swing

I'm struggling to understand the LayeredHighlighter. I have two highlights. 
One I highlight text when the textarea area is created. The other highlighter is the highlight you get when you scroll over text.

The problem I'm having is that the highlighting I use with the mouse does not overlap the highlight on the text that was set when the textarea was created.

Below is the text being highlighted when the textarea is created

[image: Original highlight]

When I use the mouse to highlight the whole text it does not go on top

[image: With selection]

I think I need to use the LayeredHighlighter. I tried to use it by using `painter.paintLayer(...)` I used this when I created the grey coloured highlight.

Is there anyway to set my grey highlight to the back so that my mouse blue highlight will go ontop of it when I select the whole line? So the whole line should be blue

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

In the [Core Swing book, page 262](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=E0HGXKrxcS8C&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=layeredhighlighter&source=bl&ots=jg2Q8CMpI2&sig=cqWGo0aRgvBM3tunUYfd1vjzvVs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC-vqcxNPMAhVKF5QKHeQiBiIQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=layeredhighlighter&f=false), there is some documentation about the semantics (unlike in the API reference). It seems to boil down to a system with just two layers. There isn't much control over the z-order other than using a `Highlighter.HighlightPainter` that is *not* a `LayeredHighlighter.LayerPainter` (somewhat counter-intuitive design pattern), vs using one that is. Highlight painters of the first type will get to go first (in an arbitrary order). Then all the `LayerPainter`s. Also in arbitrary order, but we could guess that the selection highlight gets painted first (it uses a `LayerPainter`), and then other `LayerPainter` highlights on top.

So the solution (that works for me) is to add highlights using a `Highlighter.HighlightPainter`. Make sure it is *not* a `LayeredHighlighter.LayerPainter`; i.e. probably use an anonymous class deriving straight from `Highlighter.HighlightPainter`. Don't use `DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter`, because that is a subclass of `LayeredHighlighter.LayerPainter`. But perhaps your `Highlighter.HighlightPainter` implementation could keep a reference to an instance of `DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter`, and relay `paint(..)` requests to it — thus avoiding having to write the painting code from scratch. This will solve the problem illustrated, as whenever a part of the view is repainted, this `HighlightPainter`-not-`LayerPainter` is going to fill its part of the background before the selection's `HighlightPainter`-yes-`LayerPainter`. (Note that it doesn't matter what `Highlighter` is used, `Layered` or not, only the `HighlightPainter` of a particular highlight.)

(Now, in my case, I was also interested in having the underlying highlights showing through the selection highlight. I did this by using a semi-transparent selection colour: `jtextpane.setSelectionColor(Color(80, 120, 255, 100))`.)

Answer (score 2):

never used `J/XLayer`, but there are another way painting to the [JViewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614972/passing-current-date) or [Glass/RootPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715807/layering-multiple-glasspanes-in-a-root-container), then theoretically it could be able to create 3_layer painting

EDIT

by using `J/XLayer` is there another issue that you have to simulating `MouseEvent` for example [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045963/714968)

Answer (score 1):

@Evgeni answer is correct. It took me some time to find this post on how to simultaneously render Highlights and Selections for my JEditorPane.

```
final Highlighter highlighter = new DefaultHighlighter();
editorPane.setHighlighter(highlighter);
editorPane.setSelectionColor(new Color(80, 120, 255, 100));

final HighlightPainter matchPainter = new Highlighter.HighlightPainter() {

    final DefaultHighlightPainter helper = newDefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics g, int p0, int p1, Shape bounds, JTextComponent c) 
    {
        helper.paint(g, p0, p1, bounds, c);
    }
};

highlighter.addHighlight(iIndexToTradeId, iIndexToTradeId+sTradeId.length(), matchPainter);
```

Answer (score 0):

My hat is off to @Evgeni Sergeev, as I put to good use his observation that `HighlightPainter` draws *under* `LayerPainter` as shown here:

Referring to this image [Black Bar at the top of a Brown Box, with a Blue Box to the right of the Brown Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCsbL.gif), the black line just inside the top of the brown box is drawn by:

```
class LineHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlightPainter
```

This gives me a free implementation of LayerPainter, which is only an interface.

The brown and blue boxes are drawn by:

```
class RVMHighlightPainter implements Highlighter.HighlightPainter
```

I copied the code for both of these from `UnderlineHighlightPainter`, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765489/jtextpane-highlighting-issue/19767070#19767070%20%22here%22.).