# Java table highlight-on-highlight issue

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, jtable, gtk3

When I run a particular commercial java app on OpenJDK 21 on Windows I can highlight a block of text in a selected table row and the selection stands out from the rest of the cell.

[image: Highlighted block in selected row]

Unfortunately on an Ubuntu-based box the highlight doesn't show up, possibly because I have messed with the theme currently in use...

[image: Text selected but not highlighted]

I tried building a simple test app using Swing JTable but couldn't get it to allow me to select chunks of text in a cell without going into edit mode. Any suggestions as to how the example is likely to have been constructed so I can do some experiments in the absence of the commercial app source?

(Tips as to the possible GTK3 (?) theme value being used for the selection colour would be appreciated as well!)

I did see [How to use LayeredHighlighter - One highlight on top of another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9083206/628504) but is it likely that the commercial app went to such lengths? I would have thought this should be stock behaviour, if I could only find the right combination.